# Retention Cohort Query in SQL

Tags: mysql, retention

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+---------+------------+----------+
| User_id | start_date | end_date |
+---------+------------+----------+
| 123     | 1/1/2015   | 3/1/2015 |
| 234     | 1/1/2015   | 1/1/2015 |
| 345     | 2/1/2015   | 3/1/2015 |
| 456     | 3/1/2015   | 3/1/2015 |
| :       |            |          |
| :       |            |          |
+---------+------------+----------+
```

Output should be:

**Months_since_live**

```
+-------------+---+---+---+---+
|             | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
+-------------+---+---+---+---+
| Jan_signups | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Feb_signups | 1 | 1 | 0 |   |
| Mar_signups | 1 | 0 |   |   |
| :           |   |   |   |   |
| :           |   |   |   |   |
+-------------+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

This is generally not a great format for your output because you'll have to add a new column for every new length of retention you want to track data for. e.g. if in April you want to see how many of your January signups are still around, you'll have to add a "4" column to your output.

Better output would be month_of_signup, months_active, users_retained (count) then you can pivot to your heart's content.

If you need to aggregate the start_date into months or transform it into a string you can add that to both the select and the group by.

If you really want your original output:

```
select concat(date_format(start_date, '%b'),'_signups') as month,
sum(if(timestampdiff(month, start_date, end_date) >= 0, 1, 0) as '0',
sum(if(timestampdiff(month, start_date, end_date) >= 1, 1, 0) as '1',
sum(if(timestampdiff(month, start_date, end_date) >= 2, 1, 0) as '2',
sum(if(timestampdiff(month, start_date, end_date) >= 3, 1, 0) as '3'
from your_table
group by month
```

However, that's going to get really confusing when the next year rolls around and you have two Januaries in your table.  I'd suggest adding the year to your output and aggregation as well.